# Convert bytea to geometry column with PostGIS

Tags: postgis, postgresql, openstreetmap, geometry, well-known-binary

I am trying to create a geometry column from `bytea`.

I imported OSM data using `ogr2ogr` using the command

```
ogr2ogr -f PostgreSQL -nln bahamas_multipolygon PG:"dbname=openstreetmap user=postgres password=xxx" bahamas-latest.osm.pbf multipolygons
```

The output is when running the `select` query is fine

```sql
select wkb_geometry, osm_id, ogc_fid, "natural"
from public.bahamas_multipolygon as sd
where sd.natural = 'water';
```

[image]

Now I want to convert `wkb_geometry` to a WKT string representation (or) geometry column.

I tried with `ST_GeomFromWKB`, `ST_GeomFromEWKB` and tried explicit casting the column to `::geometry` but all resulted in the same error.

```
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

I looked at various similar answers but none of them helped. What is it with `bytea` that I am missing to help me convert to geometry?

Comment: Please run `SELECT PostGIS_Full_Version();` - if that function does not exist, you either **do not** have the extension installed, or it is installed in a schema not listed in your `search_path`.

Comment: Oh God! Yes, I forgot to install extension. It worked once I installed the extension. Thanks :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Verify that you have the PostGIS extension installed, or if the containing schema is added to your `search_path`!

---

Run

```
SELECT PostGIS_Full_Version();
```

to verify the installation - if that function does not exist, the extension is not installed.